# Component is not re-rendering after state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch videos from youtube and display on browser.. I'm able to get videos and update state property. ( checked with console log)

But SearchResults component is not re-rendering when I update the state property. Here is my component

```
class Application extends React.Component {

    state = {videos: []};

    handleFormSubmit = async term => {
        const res = await youtubeApi.get("search", {
            params: {q: term}
        });

        this.setState({videos: res.data.items})
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <SearchForm onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}/>
                <SearchResults videos={this.state.videos}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

SearchResults component

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {

    state = {featured: null, suggested: []};

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.videos.length > 0)
            this.setState({featured: this.props.videos[0].id.videoId});

        if (this.props.videos.length > 1)
            this.setState({suggested: this.props.videos.slice(1)});
    }

    handleSidebarVideoClick = id => {
        this.setState({featured: id})
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <Video video={this.state.featured}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <Sidebar videos={this.state.suggested} onSidebarVideoClick={this.handleSidebarVideoClick}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: so state.videos is updated?
did the render function run?
if so, the issue must be in the <SearchResults /> component. Check if its render function runs too. maybe you have a shouldComponentUpdate() function implemented somewhere?

Comment: Could you include the code for the `SearchResults` component as well? It might be that you are putting props in state and that they are not updated, or something of that nature.

Comment: @Tholle I updated my question

Comment: Yes, you are putting props in state in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, which is only run when the component is mounted. You can use `componentDidUpdate` if you want to put props in state on update as well, or just use props directly in the render method if that's appropriate.

Comment: @TeomanTıngır are you trying to make updates to your component based on `componentDidMount`? If so that only runs once

Comment: @Ziarno Yes it is updated. I just log the render method and it also works as well and I'm sure there is no shouldComponentUpdate method in both of components

Comment: You probably need `shouldComponentUpdate` instead to check for things, or just read from props directly in `render()`

Comment: @Tholle ohh you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `getDerivedStateFromProps()` in your `SearchResults` component in order to expect a new props value when it changes on parent component.
`ComponentDidMount` is called once the component is mounted, not when it receives prop values when it changes every time.

So you should have something like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.videos.length > 0) {
      return {
        featured: nextProps.videos[0].id.videoId
      };
    }
    if (nextProps.videos.length > 1) {
      return {
        suggested: nextProps.videos.slice(1)
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you checked the component's `state` property. You most likely checked `this.state` which does get updated. The question is what is `this`.

There is no evidence you bound your event handlers to the component as recommended in the dev guide. So the keyword `this` doesn't reflect the Component, it reflects the DOM element receiving the event.

To test this, console log the value of `this` in you event handlers.

To fix:

```
this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
this.handleSidebarVideoClick = this.handleSidebarVideoClick.bind(this);
```

in their respective classes constructors.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html